# Prevent Rsync from changing ownership of the folder of the exclude list

Tags: rsync, ownership

I know there's lot of question around the subject here but I did not found the answer yet (after many research).

I have to upload the code of a web through `rsync` with a command line like the following:

```
rsync -rlvz --exclude-from=exclude_list.txt  -e "ssh -i /home/user/.ssh/rsa -o  -p $PORT" * user@$INSTANCE_IP:/home/public_html/foo/
```

The issue here is `rsync` is changing the the ownership from `__apache:apache__` to `__user:apache__` of certain folder inside  `/home/public_html/foo/` even if the folders are in the `exclude_list.txt` and causing downtime on our production website.

Any ideas to prevent `rsync` from changing ownership of these specific folders?

Comment: After reading again my question, I realised it misses some informations. It's on the destination server that I need to keep the __apache:apache__ ownership on certain folders

Comment: The `rsync` command should have a `-p, --perms` flag that says it preserves permissions.  It will most likely require that you are the root user on the destination machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run it as `root` and use the `--chown` switch.

```
rsync -rlvz --chown=user:group your_options source destination
```

That will set the ownership and to your required user and group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to keep the ownership on the destination folder not to keep the owner from the origin like the -a option will . I will edit my question to make it less ambiguous

Comment: @MathieuArtus See my update.